# How to chain multiple script commands?

Tags: vimscript, highlight

I have used this script to be able to highlight results from test reports: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words

When using it in Vim, it works fine when I type `:Highlight 1 FAILED` (For some reason the numpad-keys don't work).

Unfortunately, this is not session persistent, so what I was planning to do is create a chain of these commands and add them to my notepad where I store frequently used commands. In this case, I could use it every time I open a test-report.

So for example, I would use: `:Highlight 1 FAILED | :Highlight 2 PASSED`. Unfortunately this didn't work. I also tried escaping the pipe and removing the second colon.
Strangely enough, when trying `echo "a" | echo "b"` it **does** work?

What am I doing wrong here? How do I chain these commands properly?

Comment: Note that even though the context is the same as [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37158/how-to-add-commands-from-an-external-script-to-vimrc?noredirect=1#comment67698_37158),
It is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: See `:help command-bar`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I must be missing something obvious? What am I supposed to see there? I see some explanation about how to use "bar" (which I guess is a strange way of describing the pipe symbol?), but isn't that precisely what I did with the echo's in my example?

Comment: Maybe it’s `:help :command-bar`; should be the explanation on adding the `-bar` attribute to user-commands to allow the chaining to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly happens when using the `|` after a custom command (that is defined using `:com` (see in the help at [:h :command-bar](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-bar).

In short, if you know that your argument cannot contain the `|` character, you should add the `-bar` argument to your command definition, so that a user can always chain several commands using the `:A | :B` syntax. (This means the command `:A` was defined as followed `:command -bar A ....`)

In your specific case this doesn't seem to be the case. The usual work-around to that is to wrap the command into an `:exe` statement, which are then allowed to be chained by using the bar `|`. So you can use:

```
:exe ":Highlight 1 FAILED" | :exe ":Highlight 2 PASSED"
```

Comment: Thanks! The sample you gave worked indeed, so upvoted already! 
I'm trying to understand the rest of your answer though. You say something about not being allowed to use `|` in a command, but in the A-B example you do use one? What's the difference there? Also: where should I add this `-bar` argument? Simply behind the command? Like `:command A | :command B -bar` ? I've never seen this kind of syntax in Vim before.
I've been exclusively using Vim for 2 years now, and I still feel like there's so much I don't understand yet :)

Comment: you need to add the `-bar` to the definition of the command. E.g. you need to define command `A` like this: `:command -bar A :echo foobar` and then you can use `:A | echo "bar"`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. I it didn't work in this case (but you already pointed that out in your answer), but it's good to know for the future.